# The connection to the server was unsuccessful Android ionic2 Angular

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to run an Android App in the Emulator and Android Device.My App is built using `ionic 2 Angular` framework.

After the Successful build `ionic cordova build android`, I installed the app in the emulator, installation also successful. however, when i run the app by clicking on the app its giving me the following error in the popup.

> **Error:** The connection to the server was unsuccessful
>   //android_asset/www/index.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out from this [Q/A forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful/67584/7).

Add the next line into the `config.xml` in side the tag.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the most optimal solution but it works for me. Add this to your config.xml. This lengthens the loading time for index.html

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
```